# C++ substr out_of_range error

Tags: c++, string

I am new to C++ language and I was looking for clear answer to my problem but with no result. What I am trying to do is get `substr` value of the string which is single line in text file. When I run compilation like this I receive first twelve letters of the sentence and I don't have problem with that:

`a[count] = sentence.substr(0,12);`

but when I am trying to change `pos` from `0` to any other value for example:

`a[count] = sentence.substr(1,12);`

I receive error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of std::out_of_range
>   what(): basic_string::substr: _pos (which is 1) this -> size() (which is 0)

I checked it with YT and online guides and no one had problem with `substr`.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
Sorry for confusion cause. This is a part of the code:

```
string sentence;
string a[10000];
string next_line[10000];

main()
{

int count = 1;    


fstream file;
file.open("converted.txt",ios::in);

while(!file.eof())
{
   getline(file, line);
   next_line[count] = line;
   sentence = next_line[count];

   a[count] = sentence.substr(1,12);

   count++;
}

}
```

Comment: Does `sentence` has more than 12 characters?

Comment: This is not a [mcve] ... What is sentence? What does it contain?

Comment: `sentence` has 24 characters

Comment: Did you print out how long `sentence` is? The error message suggests it is empty.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @FilipKočica How would it matter?If the string has less than `12` characters, then all of them would be returned.Right?

Comment: The error message tells you the problem. The first parameter `_pos` must not be larger than the `size()` of the string.

Comment: @FilipKočica I read it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) and tried it [here](https://ideone.com/Wm72ER)

Comment: Oke you are right

Comment: Can you read guys? I wrote it that sentence has 24 characters and there is no error when I type `a[count] = sentence.substr(0,12);` only when I change `_pos` value.

Comment: Still, not a [mcve]. What is the content of the file you are reading? I assume one line (or multiple lines)  is empty? Check the size of `sentence` before calling `substr`.

Comment: @MrDominikku Yes we all can read.Otherwise we would not be responding to your question(without [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and comments.`sentence.substr(0,12);` would work on empty `sentence` but `sentence.substr(1,12);` would fail.So you have to provide more information like what's in the file.Check what you actually get in `a[count]` after `sentence.substr(0,12)`.That will help you.

Comment: File has 6300 lines. Mostly dates and numbers which I don't want to share with anyone. I still don't get it why you can't understand that each line has 24 characters and when I use `a[count] = sentence.substr(0,12);` I get first 12 numbers of the string (that's works) but when I change `_pos` and I want get numbers from 1 to 13 I get this error. I have no idea why, that's why asking you guys for help.

Comment: Read [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: `cout<<a[1]<<endl;` return to console `12.12.2012;5` when using `sentence.substr(0,12);` and error when using `sentence.substr(1,12);`

Comment: The condition `while(!file.eof())` will give you an extra **empty** line at the end of the file. The condition will not be set until *after* `getline` has failed one read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [feof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/)

> This indicator is generally set by a **previous** operation on the stream
>   that attempted to read at or past the end-of-file.

It means you have read **one more row**, before condition was false.
This row was **empty**.

From [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

> The substring is the portion of the object that starts at character
>   position pos and spans len characters **(or until the end of the string,
>   whichever comes first)**.

So if you used `substr` with first parameter 0, it was ok, it was skipped. But if you passed 1 as first parameter, which was more that the string had characters, an exception was thrown.

---

Here is the correct reading from file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string sentence;
string a[10000];
string next_line[10000];

int main()
{

    int count = 1;
    std::string line;

    fstream file;
    file.open("test.txt",ios::in);

    while(getline(file, line))
    {
       next_line[count] = line;
       sentence = next_line[count];

       a[count] = sentence.substr(1,12);

       count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! That the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, next time try to debug your code and you would see there is an empty row read from the file :-) Have a nice day.